# Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager]

Tags: laravel, email

I am getting this error  InvalidArgumentException Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager] on Laravel 5.6 and I'm having this issue both on my local machine and on the test website the internet.  I started off using just gmail with smtp and was getting some login problems, so i then came across mailgun and set everything up with that.  I have my .env file set up (the test website shows driver as mailgun properly)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=PWD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

My config/email is as follows

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'domain',
    'secret' => 'key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
],

'host' => env('smtp.mailgun.org', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

'port' => env('587', 587),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('uname'),

'password' => env('pwd'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
      ],
    ],

  ];
```

config/services is

```
 'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('domain'),
    'secret' => env('key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
  ],

  'ses' => [
    'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
      'region' => 'us-east-1',
  ],

  'sparkpost' => [
    'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
  ],

  'stripe' => [
      'model' => App\User::class,
      'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
       'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
  ],

  ];
```

Ever since adding this stuff ive gotten the problem. Ive was getting output to the log file and as i mentioned earlier when using gmail smtp i did not get this driver error. I have tried the laravel docs using maiables and that didnt help. I used this link https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-and-fast-emails-with-laravel-5-3-mailables as a guide and even then i got the same error.  Ive done a dd on the Route

```
  Route::get('test', function(){
  dd(Config::get("mail"));
  Mail::raw('Sending emails with Mailgun and Laravel is easy!',        function($message)
  {dd(Config::get("mail"));
    $message->to('email@email.email');
    });
});
```

with the following results

```
  array:9 [▼
 "mailgun" => array:2 [▼
  "domain" => "domain"
  "secret" => "key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ]
  "host" => "smtp.mailgun.org"
  "port" => 587
  "from" => array:2 [▼
   "address" => "hello@example.com"
  "name" => "Example"
 ]
"encryption" => "tls"
"username" => null
"password" => null
"sendmail" => "/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs"
"markdown" => array:2 [▼
"theme" => "default"
"paths" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
]
```

Admitantly I'm new to Laravel so i was pretty eager to try to resolve this, as that is the best way to learn, but with even google I personally wasnt finding alot of help so i reach out to some of the experts here on SO.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are you using the config? I can you dumping it, but where and how are you actually using it?

Comment: Hello, I have the config dump in the web.php under the routes folder i am just directing to a test page for troubleshooting.  One of the resources I was going thru said to dump results and see what output was being done.  I was trying to be through and put all the code I have related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Mailgun you should change to this in your `.env`:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
```

Which will tell Laravel to use this config from `config/services`:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'domain',
    'secret' => 'key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
],
```

**Edit:**

Change your `config/email.php` to [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/mail.php). Copy paste replace everything in your current config and the error should be resolved. You should do the same for `config/services.php` - copy from [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/services.php).

Reason: you deleted the `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),` line from your config and Laravel is unable to resolve the driver.

Even if you just add this line you'll run into more errors because of these lines:

```
'username' => env('uname'),

'password' => env('pwd'),
```

The first argument for `env(..)` function is which line in `.env` file to look for the variable. The 2nd is the default value if the variable is not found in the `.env`. You don't have variables `uname` and `pwd` in your env (at least from what you've shown). And you don't provide the default value either.

Long story short, don't edit your mail config, edit the variables in the `.env` file instead.

Comment: I do have it set up like that on my test site thats on a live site and i am getting the same error

Comment: I see, I edited the answer. That should resolve it for you.

Comment: That's it devk, which I'm sure you knew :) That solved my error, I knew it was something like that.  i had over edited things.  Like I said I'm leaning Laravel and you have done a valuable service and taught me more. So thank you, this was my solution.

Comment: Glad we solved it! Give me the nice green solved mark, please :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy content [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/services.php) in your config/services.php and [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/mail.php) in your config/mail.php

And add this in end of your app.php

```
$app->configure('services');    
$app->configure('mail');
```